# A very slow, weak and loose person

Tags: word-request, expressions, phrases

How would you normally in informal (not vulgar) English criticise a slowpoke how normally is very loose, weak and drags his feets when it comes to performing a task and you find it really difficult to deal with them?

In my language, (literally translated) we say: He's like cream.

Connotation: it is a metaphore which similizes such an individual to "cream" as it is really soft (shapability) and hard to replace (slowness)!

How do you allude to this character as a criticism figuratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sloth or Lazybones

You could use the word **sloth**, as in:

> He's such a sloth!

The Cambridge Dictionary definition of a sloth is:

> unwillingness to work or make any effort

This seems close to what you're asking for!

Another word you could use is **lazybones**, which is more informal, and still conveys the meaning. For example,

> He's such a lazybones! He didn't clean his room!

The Cambridge Dictionary state this for laxybones:

> someone who is lazy

I hope this answered your question!

Comment: Thank you @Invent Palooza , but I was not only looking for a word to indicate the person's laziness! More importantly, I need to indicate the person **who's body is so loose and this is why they move so slowly** rather than being "lazy"; although the words you suggested were really helpful, but let's think twice about the concept. Now, do you think you two offered words can imply the message in my question? ;)

Comment: @A-friend Yes, I do believe so because what you said in your question was, "drags his feets when it comes to performing a task and you find it really difficult to deal with them." The wording of your question implies that its not their physical state that stops them from performing tasks, but their mental state. Therefore, the words I gave do apply. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Absolutely; you are right @Invent Palooza; it is just a mental case. Thank you very much for the help. ;)

Comment: @A-friend No problem! Glad to be of help!